# Should there be a new tag wsl2?

Tags: feature-request, tags

As Microsoft improved windows subsystem for linux to version 2 there should be some questions related to version. the new tag  kind of wsl2 could be useful.

Comment: IMO Nope. WSL2 isn't a very big thing as compared to WSL which would change questions drastically except very few them which has to do something with performance.

Comment: a  config file .wslconfig is only related to 2.0 ok.  as more questions came, let's see

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No. Not unless version 2 is somehow completely different and someone can be an expert in WSL2 and not in WSL. The version can be mentioned in the body, that is helpful, but having a different tag for every version of a tool that comes out will just complicate things.

So I'd say we really don't need separate tags for separate versions of WSL.