# Should apache2.4 be a synonym of apache2?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

I'm at fault here, as I first created that tag. However, I agree with @terdon's [answer](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/18750/should-there-be-a-new-tag-wsl2) on another question that, separate tags for separate versions of a tool aren't helpful unless there was a big change and expertise between the 2 versions if completely different.

Should [apache2.4](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/apache2.4) be a synonym of [apache2](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/apache2) in that case?

---

I have created a [synonym suggestion for the tags](https://askubuntu.com/tags/apache2/synonyms) as the Rinzwind's seems to be the preferred opinion (I assume I did it correctly).

Comment: What about just deleting that tag?

Comment: Does that mean retagging all questions? Is there an easy way to do it without editing all of them one by one? (Maybe a sort of mod hammer?)

Comment: I consider editing them one by one, attentively, to be much better than a hammer type method (which could leave some posts untagged), because it provides an opportunity to maintain those posts and fix other issues with them. 116 is not that many :)

Comment: Lets give this a couple more days before anyone acts on it just to make sure the 'votes' are handled properly.

Comment: Stack Overflow's [Apache 2.4](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/apache2.4/info) tag offers a *reason* for the new tag - so it's more a matter of "do people care about the difference" or should we simply use [tag:Apache] and an additional tag for the 2.4 feature.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes.

Comment: There should be a NO option too, I fixed that for you. :)

Answer (score -3):

No.

Comment: Now I'm tempted to answer "Maybe"...

Comment: What if I support "No"? Should I upvote or downvote this answer? **¯\\_(ツ)_/¯**

Comment: @ByteCommander Just [upvote both yes and no!](http://i.stack.imgur.com/OfhPx.png)  **>:-)**